# Android Activity findviewbyid() is null

Tags: android, android-intent, findviewbyid

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FileExplorerActivity extends Activity 
{
    public static final String TAG="ricky";
    Button button;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);<<<------------------
        if(button == null)
        Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorerActivity: button is null");
    }
    public FileExplorerActivity()
    {
       Log.d(TAG, "FileExplorer: constructor()");
    }
}
```

This is a simple Activity which is brought in front by another activity using Intent

```
Intent openFileBrowser = new Intent(this, FileExplorerActivity.class);
try
{
    startActivity(openFileBrowser); 
}
```

After running the code my LogCat file says "button is null" Why ???

Comment: where is your setContentView()?

Comment: Where's the `setContentView()` mehtod?

Comment: startActivity(openFileBrowser); already brings the Activity in front

Comment: **Why do I need that???**  Read the [Developer's Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As others stated, you didn't set a layout via `setContentView()` *before*  calling `findViewById()`.

> Why do I need that?

Because [`Activity.findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) searches in the view hierachy of the current activity. If you set no view hierachy, there is nothing to find. And when this method finds nothing, it returns null.

Therefore you should add a layout after the call to `super.onCreate()`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
// ...
```

Comment: Thankyou alextsc...i had no idea what setContentView() did as I thought it only brings the activity in front...SOLVED

Comment: but what if a `TabLayoutMediator` was used and because of that, `setContentView` would make the tabs disappear?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

Comment: You should specify where in the code to place this and why it is needed to fix the poster's question. The original poster would find it hard to determine what to do with this statement if you just say that.

Answer (score 0):

Next code solves the issue (Xamarin Android)

```
public class MainActivity : WearableActivity
{
    ...

    OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        **SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RoundMain);**

        // Does not return null anymore:

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ButtonVgOk).LongClick += (s, e) => ButtonVgOkOnLongClick();

        ...
   }
```